# How to create std::string from output stream?

Tags: c++, stdstring

Forgive the simple question, but I've been at this for hours, with no success. Im trying to implement a function:

```
std::string make_date_string()
```

I am using Howard Hinnant's date lib, which allows me to do stuff like this:

```
cout << floor<days>(system_clock::now());
```

printing something like:

```
2017-07-09
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can get that output to go in a std::string so I can return it from my function, but Im getting nowhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out how I can get that output to go in a std::string so I can return it from my function, but Im getting nowhere.

In such case you can use a `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << floor<days>(system_clock::now());
std::string time = oss.str();
```

---

As a side note:

As it looks like your helper function

```
template<typename Fmt>
floor(std::chrono::timepoint);
```

is implemented as an [iostream manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), it can be used with any `std::ostream` implementation.

Comment: I was finally able to complete my quest of creating a date/time string without using ctime in a portable way, what an age we live in!

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is a good answer (which I've upvoted).

Here is an alternative formulation [using the same library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html):

```
#include "date.h"
#include <string>

std::string
make_date_string()
{
    return date::format("%F", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
}
```

which creates a `std::string` with the `"2017-07-09"` format.  This particular formulation is nice in that you don't have to explicitly construct a `std::ostringstream`, and you can easily vary the format to whatever you like, for example:

```
    return date::format("%m/%d/%Y", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
```

which now returns `"07/09/2017"`.