# Assign ostream to a datatype string in c++

Tags: javascript, c++, visual-studio

I have a below method that I can understand by name is converting the output in a pretty format to display.  But I don't understand what this code is doing and what is its return type.  How can I assign this return type to a string datatype which I want to access from `javascript`

```
std::ostream & prettyPrintRaw(std::ostream &out, const std::vector<unsigned char> &buf) {

vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator ptr = buf.begin();

vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator end = buf.end();

int i = 0;

  while (ptr != end) {

    char c = (char) *ptr; 

    if (c >= ' ' && c <= '~') {
      out.put(c);
      barCodeDataChar[i] = c;
      i++;
    }
    else
      out << '{' << (int) c << '}';

    ptr++;
  } // end while

  return out;

} // end function
```

Sorry I am not able to prettyFormat this `piece` of code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting ostream into standard string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513173/converting-ostream-into-standard-string)

Comment: or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997424/how-to-create-stdstring-from-output-stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `std::ostream &out` parameter, and use a string stream to construct you string value.

You can then use `myStringStream.str()` to get a string.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string prettyPrintRaw(const std::vector<char> &buf) {

    auto ptr = buf.begin();
    auto end = buf.end();
    std::stringstream out;

    int i = 0;

    while (ptr != end) {

        char c = (char) *ptr; 

        if (c >= ' ' && c <= '~'){
            out.put(c);
            i++;
        }
        else {
            out << '{' << (int) c << '}';
        }

        ptr++;
    }

    return out.str();
}
```

## Edit:

Obviously `std::vector` is a template class and needs a template parameter...
Also one should declare iterators with auto (according to my ide).

## Edit 2:

The line `barCodeDataChar[i] = c;` does not work in the code example given as `barCodeDataChar` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kanjio, but I had to make the below changes to make it work

```
std::string prettyPrintRaw1(const std::vector<unsigned char> &buf) {

vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator ptr = buf.begin();
vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator end = buf.end();
std::stringstream out;

int i = 0;

while (ptr != end) {

    char c = (char) *ptr; 

    if (c >= ' ' && c <= '~'){
        out.put(c);
    }
    else {
        out << '{' << (int) c << '}';
    }

    ptr++;
}

return out.str();
```

}

Comment: Also its spelled Kanjiu not Kanjio ;)